# Inserting a <br> into a text area via javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to input text into a textarea and have it start on a new line with every insert.

Currently this is my code, so when you enter a username/text and click post it will paste this into a text area.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById("post").addEventListener('click', function () {

var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
var output = document.getElementById('output');

var outputtext = username + ":" + input;
output.value += outputtext;

});
</script>
```

currently the output looks like this:

```
Username1:Text1Username2:Text2Username3:Text3
```

Where As i want it to display as:

```
Username1:Text1
Username2:Text2
Username3:Text3
```

Cheers for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JUst add the `<br>` as `\n`to the string of `outputtext`:

```
var outputtext = username + ":" + input +"\n";
```

**\n** - a new line character **n** that must be escaped with backslash **\** and encapsulated in double quotation marks **"**

Comment: this didn't work as it just displayed - Username1:Text1/n

Comment: @T.script  It MUST be `backslash` in double quotation `"`  ie. `"\n"`

Comment: This worked, and I was just being silly, Thank you

Comment: No problem, I have updated the answer as well. :)